# Why does my second button (delete button) have the same function to my first button (add button)

Tags: php, mysql, switch-statement, case

My Website is build using MVC (Model,View,Controller) who does my second button which is delete have the same function to my first button which is add. So, instead it deletes, it just also add data.

This is my control.php

```
if(isset($_GET['action']))
{switch($_GET['action']){
case 'del': delete_person_add();
case 'add': add_person(); break;
case 'find': find_person(); break;
case 'view': view_person(); break;
case 'delete': delete_person(); break;

case 'update': update_person(); break;
case 'medical': medical_person(); break;
default:
include "model/persons_model.php";
$persons = view_person_model();
include "admin.php";
}

function delete_person_add(){
include "delete.php";
$persons = delete_person_models();
include "add.php";
}
function add_person(){ 
include "model/persons_model.php";
$persons = add_person_model();
include "add.php";
}
```

and this is my code of my button in the addview.php

```
<button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-primary">Add 
Applicant</button>
```

and this is also my code for my view add.php for my delete button it is inside a table

```
<tbody>
<?php
if(isset($persons)){
foreach ($persons as $p){
echo '
<tr>
<td>'.$p['id'].'</td>
<td>'.$p['firstname'].'</td>
<td>'.$p['middlename'].'</td>
<td>'.$p['lastname'].'</td>
<td>'.$p['age'].'</td>
<td>'.$p['contactno'].'</td>
<td>'.$p['agent'].'</td>
<td>'.$p['dateapplied'].'</td>
<td>'.$p['datemedical'].'</td>  
<td>'.$p['foreignagency'].'</td>    
<td>'. "<input type='submit' name='del'/>".'</td>
</tr>';
}
}
?>
</tbody>
```

and lastly this is my code for the model delete.php

```
<?php
function delete_person_models(){
//connect to the server
$conn= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","people");
//check the connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno($conn)){
echo "Error";
}
else{
//echo "connect Ok";    
}
if(isset($_GET['del']))
{
    $id = $_GET['del'];
    $sql1 = "DELETE FROM persons WHERE id='$id'";
    $res = mysqli_query($sql1) or die ("Failed".mysqli_error());
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=persons.php'>";
}


}
?>
```

Comment: According to your switch statement the button in your code will call the `delete_person_add();` function. It seems you just used the wrong name for that button.

Comment: You're missing a `break` in the switch statement.

Comment: @tshimkus the name of the button is "del". The delete_person_add(); is a function

Comment: @RyanLee It still doesn't fix

Comment: I understand that, but you said "instead it deletes, it just also add data" which is exactly what`delete_person_add();` does. That function is tied to the button in your code example which has the name "del" instead of "delete" (which would call the function you want)

Answer (score 1):

Your button definition is wrong. I should be:

```
<button type="submit" name="action" value="add" class="btn btn-primary">
    Add Applicant
</button>

<button type="submit" name="action" value="del" class="btn btn-primary">
    Delete Applicant
</button>
```

Comment: It still do the same. maybe the error is in the control.php switch case statement, but I can't figure it out

Comment: Or maybe because they're in the same form?

Comment: @YnneLOnce, the error is in your switch statement. If you want "del" to delete , that case needs to execute `delete_person()` and not `delete_person_add()`

Comment: delete_person is just a dummy function, because I'm trying different ways to do it